# ODATA implementaion with ado.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ado.net, odbc, odata

Is it possible to create an ODATA webapi service with ADO.NET rather than entity framework?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. See <https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask>. In simplest terms, yes, ADO.NET can be used against ODBC data sources without using EF.